# Can string resources containing %1$s or @string/some_string be included in a layout XML

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

In Android Studio, is there a way to either use `%1$s` or nested string resources from `strings.xml` in a layout XML file?

For example:

strings.xml

```
<string name="help_menu_title">Help</string>
<string name="help_tooltip">Please see \'%1$s\' menu for more information.</string>
```

my_layout.xml

```
<textview
    text="@string/help_tooltip" />
```

or

strings.xml

```
<string name="help_menu_title">Help</string>
<string name="help_tooltip">Please see \'@string/help_menu_title\' menu for more information.</string>
```

my_layout.xml

```
<textview
    text="@string/help_tooltip" />
```

Or must the text of the `textview` be re-assigned using `String.format` to include the 'nested' string?